# May I do redirection streams and output to command line same time?

Tags: windows, cmd, io-redirection

My system is Windows XP x32

When I enter command in cmd.exe I can redirect output, like that's:

> ping  1>log.txt  2>err.txt

But then there is no ouput in display.

Can I redirect output to file and displaying it same time?

Comment: google for `tee for windows`

Comment: @stephan, yes, it's way